# How to set margin on the 2nd page of window print? 'window.print()'

Tags: jquery

[first image are the script used to print and the css used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96sD0.png)

[second image - sample print. 2nd page has no margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGsde.png)

Comment: what's your problem?

Comment: can you add an image indicating where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [the HTML box model](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_boxmodel.asp), when you need some internal space in a container you should use the padding property, or add some margin to its parent. So add some padding to your @page elements. **Don't** add it to the html or body properteies because they applay to all the document (including all the pages).
e.g.:

```
@page {
  margin: 2cm 1 3cm 1cm; //or padding: 2cm 1 3cm 1cm;
}
```

or don't modify the @page{margin} in the first place... most browsers have default margins configured.

Comment: i modified the @page{margin} to remove the default header and footer of window.print() function.

Comment: Do you mean to remove the fact that tables headers get printed in every page?